# <div> over <canvas>... inside another <div>

Tags: html, canvas

I have a weird problem that I'm not able to solve. It should seems the same as some other problem I have read about the relation between  and , but this is another thing. LEt me explain all this:

First, I've been working with this code. This works as it should:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1068" height="814" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border:1px solid #707070; z-index:-15;">
Tu browser no soporta canvas
</canvas>

<div id="contenedorpregunta" style="background-color: transparent; position: absolute; top: 170px; left: 110px; width: 500px; height: 455px; z-index:5;">
(...)
</div>
```

This shows the div content as it was expected over the canvas, both attached to the 0,0.

Now, instead, I need to show the game centered in the webpage, so, i thought in this.

```
<div align="center">
  <canvas style="position: relative;  (...)">
  </canvas>

  <div id="contenedorpregunta" style=" position: relative;(...)">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is not working, the div that previously was over the canvas now is right behind... ¿why? I tried with inherit positioning too, the result is the same. I don't know how to attack this problem and I would be very grateful with any help you could give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center the container div in a web page horizontally, just provide a width to the container element and use `margin: auto;` that's all you need, if you want to horizontally as well as vertically centered you need to use `position: absolute;`

```
.totally_centered {
   height: 500px;
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -250px; /* Half of container height */
   margin-left: -150px; /* Half of container width */
}
```

And still if you are confused why the div went behind, I've no idea why it went behind and how, but you could use `z-index` to re-arrange the stack level of the element

Comment: I think I understand. You are telling me to throw away the parent div and symple to refix both canvas and div to the center. About what is this happening, note that I'm already using z-index. Thank you for the fast answer, ill this this right now.

Comment: If you want it totally centered wrap up your stuff inside a container and use the styles I provided in `.totally_centered` class

Comment: Well it still doesn't display the thing as I'd wish but you already gave me the way to keep on. Thank you very much, I'll take this question (my first one) as answered. See you soon!

Comment: @Alien, in fact, it worked perfectly, as you predicted. I just confused height and width coordinates for a second, showing a weird perspective. All fixed and all okay!